# Edit author/committer of multiple commits based on commit message

Tags: git, git-commit, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

I am looking to edit the author/committer of several commits whose message is prefixed with [TEST].

I know that you can edit the authors with environment variables but I can't find it by searching with the commit message.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="oldmail@domain.tld"
CORRECT_NAME="Useername"
CORRECT_EMAIL="newmail@domain.tld"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

We should be able to integrate a regex like this "[TEST]*":

```
if commit message = "[TEST]*" then 
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [third-party](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) git-filter-repo(1):

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback='
if commit.message.startswith(b"[TEST]") and commit.author_email == b"oldmail@domain.tld":
    commit.committer_name = b"Username"
    commit.committer_email = b"newmail@domain.tld"
    commit.author_name = b"Username"
    commit.author_email = b"newmail@domain.tld"
'
```

This Python callback (see [manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html)) lets you change the commit in-place.

You will need to pass `--force` as well in order to do the change because
this is a destructive update that cannot (in general) be undone.

#### git-filter-branch(1)

git-filter-branch(1) is effectively [deprecated](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CABPp-BEr8LVM+yWTbi76hAq7Moe1hyp2xqxXfgVV4_teh_9skA@mail.gmail.com/t/#mc286a8705d3d389d5e6720ec2133a2e8bae294e2) and no one that I've seen
has recommended its usage.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works perfectly. I took the liberty of editing your answer so that it fits perfectly to my question.